# Quote and single quote are being changed to characters

Tags: php, symfony, escaping, double-quotes

I have a VueJs form and pass all data inside a sanitizer.

The problem:
`C'est l'été` become `C&#039;est l&#039;été`.

Result: with Twi the text is not correctly displayed:

[image]

Same result inside the database:

[image]

How can I (after sanitizer usage) convert the text for an human-readable exprerience?

Comment: They're being converted to HTML entities. Probably the sanitizer doing it.

Comment: Is it possible to revert this change?

Comment: The real question is do you really need HTML sanitation? Certainly seems like you shouldn't be doing that before you store the values in the database. Sanitation should be done before you display values that you believe might have some user defined HTML, not before you store them in the database.

Comment: why is there a `<`/`&lt;` in front of your `C`? looks to me that something is *added* and it's not just escaping. Since you provide no code at all and also don't tell which database this is, the only thing to say is: yeah, something is escaping one time too often ... or even two times too often, and apparently nothing is removing the escaping but only escaping on top.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of html sanitization and for the data that is being inserted in that way you can use a function like this if you are using php :

```
$str = "This is some &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt; text.";
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str);
```

or

```
$txt= 'This is some&lt';
              $character = array(
                         '<' => '&lt;',
                         "'" => '&#039;', 
                         '"' => '&quot;', 
                         '>' => '&gt;');
            foreach($character as $key => $value)
            {
                $txt = str_replace($key,$value,$txt);
            }
```